# HTML and Javascript: Why does video not go fullscreen?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a video with custom controls and some javascript to control them. heres my code:

```
<div id ="video-container">
              <video class = "jack7" width="409" height="230" id = "video">
                <source src="<?php echo($videourl); ?>" type="video/mp4">  
                Your browser does not support this video. Try chrome!
              </video>
              <div id="video-controls">
                <button type="button" id="play-pause" ><img id = "playbtn" src="img/icons/play.png"></button>
                <input type="range" id="seek-bar" step="0.01" value="0">
                <button type="button" id="mute"><img id = "mutebtn" src="img/icons/unmute.png"></button>
                <input type="range" id="volume-bar" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" value="1">
                <button type="button" id="full-screen"><img id = "fsbtn" src="img/icons/fullscreen.png"></button>
              </div>

          </div>

            <script src="controls.js"></script>

    var video = document.getElementById("video");    
    var fullScreenButton = document.getElementById("full-screen");

  fullScreenButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
              if (video.requestFullscreen) {
                video.requestFullscreen();
                document.getElementById("video-container").requestFullscreen();
              } else if (video.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                video.mozRequestFullScreen(); // Firefox
              } else if (video.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
                //video.webkitRequestFullscreen();
                document.getElementById("video-container").webkitRequestFullscreen();
              }
            });
```

When I click the full screen button the entire screen goes black apart from a small part that displays the video in its no-fullscreen size along with the controls. Why does the video not display fullscreen?

Comment: It looks like with the webkit-prefixed version, you are making the *container* full screen, not the video element. And the video element has a width and height, so it is doing what it has been told to do. The non-prefixed version is setting both video *and* then the container to be full screen, but you can only have one fullscreen element at any given time so the latter most likely overrode the former.

Comment: @mherzig what do you suggest i do?